# How to read Discord Embed Messages? (Discord Java JDA)

Tags: java, arrays, filter, discord, discord-jda

I am trying to read embedded discord messages and send a message back that pings a certain role once a keyword is matched against the String[] array that would search for every value in the embedded message.

Changing this String array works for text messages but I can't seem to fix it for embedded messages.

```
String[] messageSent = event.getMessage().getContentRaw().split(" ");
```

Code I'm Using for Embedded Messages:

```
public void onGuildMessageReceived(@Nonnull GuildMessageReceivedEvent event)
    {
        String[] messageSent = event.getMessage().getEmbeds().stream().spliterator().toString().split(" ");
        for(int x = 0; x < messageSent.length; ++x) {
            if (messageSent[x].contains("Red") || messageSent[x].contains("Green") || 
                messageSent[x].contains("Blue"))
            {
                if(event.getMember().getUser().isBot())
                
                {
                    event.getChannel().sendMessage("<@&825803783188071069> Color Matched!").queue();
                }
                else
                {
                    event.getChannel().sendMessage("You are not <@210243798806753280> please stop chatting here!").queue();
                    event.getMessage().delete().queue();
                }
            }

            }
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `event.getMessage().getEmbeds()` to retrieve the embeds.

[The javadoc comes in handy all the time](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Message.html#getEmbeds())